# How to reset a file to a particular commit with JGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, jgit

Consider my local repository contains more than one file, while doing checkout for a particular commit of a file, other files in the repository got deleted.

I am using following API (`git` is the instance of git repository)

```java
git.checkout().setName(commitId).call()
```

Is this correct way to check out a particular commit of a particular file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDoc of `setName()` says

> When only checking out paths and not switching branches, use `setStartPoint(}` to specify from which branch or commit to check out files.

And for `addPath()` it states:

> If this option is set, neither the `setCreateBranch()` nor `setName()` option is considered. In other words, these options are exclusive.

Therefore I think you should use

```java
git.checkout().addPath( ... ).setStartPoint( ... ).call();
```

Comment: By the way,we can use      git.checkout().setAllPaths(true).setStartPoint(Constants.HEAD).call();  to checked out all files with latest revision...Thanks

Comment: More precise answer than mine. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your call reset the index (and can remove files no longer present in the new commit you check out)

You can look for a more precise example in [`jgit/porcelain/RevertChanges.java`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/358536aa08ba0258e505a4a1efc4e9432f255b5d/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/RevertChanges.java)

```
 // revert the changes
 git.checkout().addPath(fileName).call();
```

In your case:

```
git.checkout().setname(commitId).addPath(fileName).call()
```

Comment: If we use addPath(fileName) it is updating the latest commit...it is not considering the setname(commitId).@VonC

Comment: @RenganathanSelvaraju that could be a bug to report then.