# JGit - Checkout to specific remote commit ID hash

Tags: java, github, jgit

I'm trying to access specific commitId files using the JGit library.

Using Git command this would look like : `git checkout [COMMIT_ID]`, then my folder would checkout to the specific commit and get any file from it.

Now using JGit, I'm calling the `Git.cloneRepository()` function to get my repository (can't clone from a specific commitId here I think sadly). Then I'm trying to checkout using this : `gitRepo.checkout().setName(gitCommitId).call()`

But this is getting me the folliwing error : `Remote origin did not advertise Ref for branch COMMIT_ID. This Ref may not exist in the remote or may be hidden by permission settings.`

Which is odd because the CLI git command does work.

Maybe it is not something feasible through this lib but I didn't find anything else on the web yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setName(String name)`](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.html#setName(java.lang.String)) is more for branch name, not for commit ID.

[`setStartPoint(RevCommit startCommit)`](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.html#setStartPoint(org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit)) does use a commit ID.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36550383/6309), `git.checkout().setAllPaths(true).setStartPoint(gitCommitId).call();` would work better after your clone.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error (on GitHub the branch does exist when browsing commit ID files)

Comment: @JérémiePoisson I meant `setName()` is for branch name. Since you are passing a commit ID, you cannot use `setName()`. That being said, can you use a commit ID of the default branch cloned? Just for testing?

Comment: Yeah I got the `setName()` part don't worry.
You mean using JGit with your last method ? That's already what I'm doing. My branch is called `dev` and the commit ID I'm using is 2nd latest done on this branch.

Comment: @JérémiePoisson I meant using a commit ID from the default branch (`main` or `master`), not from the `dev` branch.

Comment: Ok using a commit ID from main branch (different from the one cloned), it seems to work indeed. Do I have to specify somehow the branch where the commit is from ?

Comment: @JérémiePoisson The thing is, the refspec might be for only one branch, instead of all branches ([as seen here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102306/)). You might need to [check what branches are there after clone](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec). And/or [specify the branch to clone](https://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/#highlighter_122068).

Comment: It your first command see to work now for all commit ID, which is odd. I didn't correctly test I guess. Thanks then !